# Ionic unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, mobile

I am trying to create the ionic project but getting the same error every time.I have try to uninstall and install everything for a fresh start but still getting the same error.

[image: Error images]

[image]

Comment: What version of ionic are you using?

Comment: ionic version 6.12.4

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a version of `typescript` that does not exist. cf [npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript).

You're using the tilde character (`~`) to specify a version in a range that doesn't exist. From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json):

> ~version “Approximately equivalent to version”, will update you to all future patch versions, without incrementing the minor version. ~1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <1.3.0.

Specifically, tilde does not resolve to 4.x and the version you specified is higher than the latest 3.x release available.

So, specify version `3.9.4` to keep it at 3.x, or the next major release `4.0.3`, or the latest.